# Best practice to access sqlite in android?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-room

In our app, we perfom operations on sqlite like CRUD operations and searching. There are two methodlogies described by google developer doc. 1. SQLIte in built methods 2. Room. Which one to use in case of performance?

Comment: use SQLite in build method

Answer (score -1):

Performance of both is same as `Room` is writing same stuff (Code) under the hood to do CRUD operations.

I would suggest you to use `Room` library as all boilerplate code used to write CRUD operation is done by Room for you. You do not need to play with cursor anymore to write repeated code again and again.

Very Useful feature is that if you make any mistake in query it is validated on compile time so you do not need to hunt for errors in case you have accidentally  written wrong query.

Hope it helps.